# Задача на динамическое программирование - Вася и конструктор чисел

Tags: python, python-3.x, динамическое-программирование

> У Васи есть любимый конструктор чисел. Он представляет из себя табличку длины 
>   N и неограниченный запас цифр от 0 до 9.
>
> Для каждого числа Вася считает его крутость. Крутость  — это сумма произведений всех пар соседних цифр в числе, но при этом числа, в которых рядом стоят две одинаковые цифры, всегда имеют крутость 0. Вася очень любит играть с конструктором, поэтому он износился, и в некоторых позициях застряли цифры. Вася хочет узнать, насколько максимальная крутость числа в изношенном конструкторе меньше крутости самого крутого числа в новом конструкторе, в котором нет застрявших цифр.

Входные данные:

> В первой строке записано число 1≤N≤10^5. Во второй строке содержится S длины N, в которой на позиции i стоит ∗ если позиция свободна, и на неё можно ставить любую цифру, в противном случае на i-й позиции записана цифра от 0 до 9.

Выходные данные:

> Выведите единственное целое число: разницу между крутостью самого крутого числа в новом конструкторе и конструкторе Васи.

Мой код:

```py
n = int(input())
table = input()
if table.replace('*', '') == '':
    print(0)
else:
    table = table.split()
    maximum = 72 * (n - 1)
    masked = 0

    # Что тут?

    print(maximum - masked)
```

Это задача на динамическое программирование, но я не знаю, какой массив создать и какие в нём рекуррентные соотношения. Буду рад любой подсказке. Желательно сегодня :)

P.S. Способы решения не важны, главное - эффективность.

Comment: См. https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/6605 Дело не в том, просите ли вы готовое решение или только подсказку: и в том, и в другом случае, люди на этом сайте не знают контекста занятий, чему вас учили, а чему нет.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko меня учили основам динамического программирования, а способы решения мне не особо важны: главное, чтобы решение было эффективным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фрагменты между предопределёнными числами независимы, поэтому Вам достаточно создать функцию, которая находит наилучшую последовательность длиной p, ограниченную слева и справа заданными числами. Например, для куска 9*8 это 7, для 9**9 это 87  и т.д.